# VSTO Outlook: How to perform a long task without blocking the Outlook main UI thread

Tags: outlook, vsto, interop, outlook-addin, office-addins

When the "To" field losew the focus from the compose window I need to perform a long task which takes some time to be completed. Now UI is getting blocked because I do it in the main UI thread so I would like to make it non-blocking. I have thought in using the async/await commands from C# as below:

```
public async void PerformLongTask()
{
   bool result = await Task.Run(() =>
         {
                // Long task here
         });
}
```

I would like to know if this is the correct way to do an asynchronous task without blocking the main UI thread in Outlook or is there some other better way to do it? If so, how? When you need to perform such long task and you need to be non-blocking, how do you usually do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

async/await or tasks are fine in Outlook as long as you don't touch any Outlook Object Model objects on that secondary thread.

If you need to touch OOM objects, do so by switching to the main thread using, for example, the `Dispatcher` object - retrieve it on the main thread from `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`, then using `Dispatcher.Invoke`/`InvokeAsync` whenever you need to do anything with Outlook objects. Since thread switching is expensive, try to batch multiple OOM hits into a single `Invoke`.

```
public async void PerformLongTask()
{
   var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
   bool result = await Task.Run(() =>
         {
                // Long task here
                //now use OOM on the main thread
                dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                   MessageBox.Show(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version);
                }); 
         });
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet?

Comment: Using Dispatcher object?

Comment: Yep, a code snippet showing how 
to  switch to main thread using Dispatcher and then invoke  or invokeasync to work with outlook objects. However if you switch to main thread again to do things with Outlook objects, you will block Outlook UI main thread, right? Or am i wrong? So then why to do long task within an async task if you then switch again to Outlook main UI thread?

Comment: See the updated answer above

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. Only one thing I would like to know: When you return to the main Outlook UI thread using Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher and then invoke the stuff, in that moment the Outlook UI does not block? Because I guess you are then executing things on the main Outlook UI thread..

Comment: Whatever is inside `dispatcher.Invoke()` will be executed on the main Outlook thread, so you really need to keep it short.

Comment: And why is it necessary to put inside the Invoke the operations you do with Outlook objects? What happens if you don't do this?

Comment: As soon as OOM detects access to any of its objects on a thread other than the main one, it will throw an exception.